# How to handle long async operations in Next.js to avoid slow page loading?

Tags: react-redux, next.js

When using `next-redux-wrapper` how do I start a long asynchronous task so that it only runs on the client?  I don’t want to use `await` on the server side since it would delay the initial page load. I’d rather set a loading flag as the task starts and show a loading indicator until it completes.

Let’s say my async operation looks like this:

```
function async takesLong(store) {
    store.dispatch({type: “LOADING”, payload: true});
    const result = await longOperation();  
    store.dispatch({type: “SETDATA”}, payload: data);
    return store.dispatch({type: “LOADING”, payload: false});
}
```

I can call this in my Next page’s `getInitialProps` function like this:

```
MyPage.getInitialProps = async ({ store, isServer }) => {
  const loader = takesLong(store)
  if (isServer) await loader;   // <-- will delay client response
  return {
    someprop: "some value"
  };
};
```

This works well if the page loads on the **client side**. The operation starts, and my page can display a loading-spinner until the operation completes. But when started on the **server side** I have a long delay before the page displays at all.  I’ve tried a number of approaches but can’t find one that works properly:

1. Starting the process on the server and not using `await` renders the page without the results being written to the store, so it has only set “loading” to true in the store and it never gets the data.
2. Passing `store` in my `props` doesn’t work - it ends up being an empty object (`{ }`) in the client.
3. Trying to run it inside my component doesn’t seem to work for a few reasons:

   a) I don’t have the `store` object accessible in the React Component (only in `getInitialProps` which won’t get called on the client).

   b) Even if I use actions instead of `store.dispatch` in the Component, when can I call it safely?  I can’t do it during `render` since it will change the Redux state, and `componentWillReceiveProps` won’t get called before the first client-side `render`

Is there a well defined pattern for deferring a long operation to the client-side when using Next?

Comment: `getInitialProps` is not intended for that. I think you are better with react lifecycle functions like `componentDidMount`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your long async task on `componentDidMount`, it will run only on client side.
React in SSR not runs `componentDidMount` lifecycle hook.

Comment: Thanks Felix, I was writing my own answer while you added this answer. I went into more detail but yours has the critical parts including the fact that `componentDidMount` does not run on server-side, so I marked yours as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Using bound actions during `componentDidMount` works. Thanks to @eenagy for the suggestion. Doing things in this order seems to do what is needed:

```
import { bindActionCreators } from "redux";
import { setLoading, setError, setData } from "../actions";

componentDidMount() {
  if (!this.props.haveData && !this.props.loading && !this.props.error) {
    this.props.setLoading(true);
    loadSomeData()        // <-- this takes a while to complete
      .then( data => {
        this.props.setData(data);
        this.props.setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch( err => {
        this.props.setError(err);
        this.props.setLoading(false);
      });
  }
}

render() {
  if (this.props.loading) return (<Loading/>);
  return (/*regular page*/);
}

export const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return bindActionCreators({ setLoading, setError, setData }, dispatch);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Component);
```

This way if the initial data is not already loaded (say by another page) it will get kicked off when the
component mounts and run asynchronously until the operation completes and
calls the actions in redux to cause the page to re-render.